# Why do I get a 404 to laravel 5.7 public subfolders?

Tags: laravel, http-status-code-404, laravel-5.7, subdirectory

I have a Laravel 5.7 project and I can't seem to understand why I get a **404 error** to the subfolders in the public directory.

Directory structure

- public

  - icons

    - css

      - file.css

Example of routes that work just fine:

- localhost/images/image.png
- localhost/css/main.css

However when i try to request a file deeper that the first subdirectory, i get a 404. For exaple:

- localhost/pugins/common/common.min.js

**file located in public/pugins/common/common.min.js**

- localhost/icons/weather-icons/css/weather-icons.min.css

**file located in public/icons/weather-icons/css/weather-icons.min.css**

Anything after localhost/FOLDER/ gets a 404 eror, even if it exists.

Any ides why?

This is the default `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have noticed just now that the first level of the subdirectories of the public folder get a 403 (Forbidden) error while try to list that directory.
Example:

- **localhost/js => 403, Forbidden**
- **localhost/js/dashboard/intro-inde.js => 404, Not found**
- **localhost/js/script.js => 200, Working fine**

Each file and directory exists in the examples above, and there is no problem with the permissions.
    My guess is that it has something to do with the .htaccess, but i have no idea how that works >.>

Comment: Check owner and permissions of the directories/files

Comment: I am runing this on localhost (wamp, windows). I forgot to mention this.

Comment: It's not the htaccess, I have the same htaccess file and I dont get 404 in public subfolders

Answer (score 2):

I remembered i had no problems in previous projects using laravel 5.1 ~ 5.5. So I have copied the .htaccess file from those projects to this one. Now everything works fine, but for one folder and its subfolders : *public/icons*; I solved this problem by creating a new folder and moving everything from "icons" to *"fonts-icons"*

Behold the power of the new .htaccess. Maybe it will help someone.

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

This one solved the problem...without the new for new routes. :D I still have no idea how it works and why, though.

Just for curiosity, maybe someone will enlighten me **d=(^_^)=b**

Answer (score 0):

You should first define that route in the routes/web.php file.

Comment: There are many subdirectories with different levels. I feel that there should be a better way than writing a route for all of that...or I am missing something? :D

Comment: if they exists as files you dont need to define routes for them

Answer (score 0):

It's not about Laravel, it's about Apache.
Apache alias /icons to Apache’s icons directory.
The easiest way to solve the problem is to rename /icons to something else.

Answer (score -2):

Error 404 is when we do nnot find any pages. Which means we have to define route in our web.php file first so as to view desired content written in the blade.php file, This error may also appear if we have not saved the file in our views in .blade.php extension